# Get last updated time of document in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have recently started using Azure Cosmos DB in our project. For the reporting purpose, we need to get last updated time of document. I could not find any suitable API to achieve it, I looked online for solution.

Could anyone please let me know for any pointer on the above requirement?
Any pointer would help me a lot.

Thanks,
Satindra

Answer (score 6):

> For the reporting purpose, we need to get last updated time of
>   document.

Each document has a system defined property called `_ts` that will tell you the date/time when the document was last updated. You simply fetch the document and look at this property to find this information.

Note: _ts is the number of seconds (not milliseconds) that have elapsed since 00:00:00 (UTC), 1 January 1970 (the unix epoch).